# How to enable SELinux on RaspberryPi's 5.10 BullsEye Lite OS

Tags: raspberry-pi, selinux

SELinux files appear on a fresh image of BullsEye 5.10 lite, RaspberryPi OS but I can not find any directions on how to enable it. This should be well documented but not found for the current RaspberryPi OS.

Comment: `SELinux files appear` which files are these? none of the basic selinux packages are installed as per [this documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup) ... so, I'm wondering what IS installed (nevermind, I found what you mean) - anyway, that documentation should help